# Ruby Rails :has_many, autosetting a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given the following Ruby-on-Rails code (1.8.6, 2.3.5):

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :modifiers,
    :conditions => ["affects_class = ?", self.name],
    :foreign_key => :affects_id
end
```

What I'm trying to do is to automatically set the `affects_class` column to `'MyClass'`.  In other words:

```
myInstance = MyClass.find(:first)
modifier = Modifier.new
modifier.affects_class = self.name # Don't want to have to do this
myInstance.modifiers << modifier
```

I don't want to have to set `modifier.affects_class`.  After all, I don't have to set `modifier.affects_id`; that's set automatically by the `has_many` relation.  Is there some option I can set on `has_many`?  Or am I stuck having to set it each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgive me if what I'll say doesn't make any sense... but I can't test here what I'm about to suggest, so...

[`railsapi.doc`](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M000966) says the following about the `:conditions` option on a `has_many` relation:

> [...] Record creations from the
>   association are scoped if a hash is
>   used. has_many :posts, :conditions
>   => {:published => true} will create published posts with
>   @blog.posts.create or
>   @blog.posts.build.

So, if you set up the condition using a hash

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :modifiers,
      :conditions => {:affects_class => self.name},
      :foreign_key => :affects_id
end
```

and create the `modifiers` using

```
myInstance = MyClass.find(:first)
myInstance.modifiers.create #or myInstance.modifiers.build
```

won't you get modifiers with the name already set?

I'm just not very confident about using `self.name`. I don't know if this is the right way to get the class' name.

Anyway, let me know if it works. It's new to me and very useful.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This did indeed exactly solve my problem!  Kudos to you.  Switching from an array to a hash, which was a good idea anyway, and then using myInstance.modifiers.create (or build) did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: self.name does work for me, but I admit that I'm using it because I'm doing metaprogramming magic to do a variation on discrete event simulation.  :)

Comment: Nice! :) I wasn't very sure about it... glad it helped!